# How can I substitute a regex only once in Python?

Tags: python, regex

So right now, `re.sub` does this:

```
>>> re.sub("DELETE THIS", "", "I want to DELETE THIS472 go to DON'T DELETE THIS847 the supermarket")
"I want to  go to DON'T  the supermarket"
```

I want it to instead delete only the first instance of "DELETE THISXXX," where XXX is a number, so that the result is

```
"I want to  go to DON'T DELETE THIS847 the supermarket"
```

The XXX is a number that varies, and so I actually do need a regex. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: why do you need regex? .. if its a series of simple patterns like this i dont think you need regex...  In fact this sounds like a clasic case of "I had a problem and I thought "I know I'll use a regex"... now you have two problems"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) for `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` you can specify the `count` argument in:

```
    re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

if you only give a count of 1 it will only replace the first

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.python.org/library/re#re.sub:

> The optional argument *count* is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced; *count* must be a non-negative integer. If omitted or zero, all occurrences will be replaced. Empty matches for the pattern are replaced only when not adjacent to a previous match, so `sub('x*', '-', 'abc')` returns `'-a-b-c-'`.

Answer (score 2):

The optional argument count is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced; count must be a non-negative integer.

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Set count = 1 to only replace the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your phrasing, "first instance," caused everyone else to answer in the direction of `count`, but if you meant that you want to delete a phrase only if it fully matches a phrase you seek, then first you have to define what you mean by a "phrase", e.g. non-lower-case characters:

```
DON'T DELETE THIS
```

In which case, you can do something like this:

```
(?<![^a-z]+)\s+DELETE THIS\s+(?![^a-z]+)
```

I'm not sure whether Python allows arbitrary-length negative lookbehind assertions. If not, remove the first `+`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for my awkward phrasing. I actually did mean to delete only the first occurence of "DELETE THIS," but thanks for contributing nevertheless :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.replace()` for this:

```
In [9]: strs="I want to DELETE THIS go to DON'T DELETE THIS the supermarket"

In [10]: strs.replace("DELETE THIS","",1) # here 1 is the count
Out[10]: "I want to  go to DON'T DELETE THIS the supermarket"
```

Comment: You can't use replace to regex match.

Comment: I dont think the OP actually needs regex... until i see a search pattern that requires it im gonna go with regex is overkill

Comment: @sudo_o Actually what the OP is trying to do here can be done with `replace()`, `regex` is good for complex patters.

Comment: What the user asked was how to do regex substitutions, you can't do that with `replace()`. Because you can do the example with `replace` it don't make it a correct answer. The OP has multiple lines with multiple patterns, the point is how to use `re.sub`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Sorry for the unclear example, I actually do need a regex, as I said in my last sentence. I.e. I want to delete the strings "DELETE THIS123" and "DELETE THIS736", but I don't know what the number is.

Comment: ahh there ya go ... thats what you should have posted from the start :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question to be more clear!