# Regex order of operations for lazy operator

Tags: regex

I made a simple regex search/replace to get rid of leading and trailing white space:

```
exampleString = '    something               '

import re

searchObject = re.compile(r'\s*(.*?)\s*')
subObject = searchObject.sub(r'\1', exampleString)

print(subObject)
```

This did what I want, but I was worried about space in between.  So I tried instead

```
exampleString2 = '    somet hing               '
```

and it still worked like I wanted.

My question is, how does the non-greedy operator decide to pass over the middle space?  Shouldn't it return `'    somet '`?

If it reads the regex from left to right, it would satisfy `.*?` before it satisfies the last `\s*`, so it would choose the smallest string of anything, as long as it can match a space, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that python runs the regex until it stops matching. Currently, it's actually matching once for every character and keeping it if it's a not a space because the `.*?` is matching nothing and it moves to the next character. The reason that lazy operator is matching nothing is because there's nothing forcing it to, so it chooses the laziest option it can: doing no work.

For example, here's what the matches look like currently: https://regex101.com/r/AzOrJZ/2

You can get what it looks like after a single match by following these directions:

[How can I substitute a regex only once in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732265/how-can-i-substitute-a-regex-only-once-in-python)

In order to improve performance, here's the regex I'd suggest for performance and fewer matches:

`\s*(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*`

This essentially matches all leading whitespace characters `\s+` then groups all non-whitespace `\S+` followed by one or more whitespace with non-whitespace `(\s+\S+)*`. Once all the non-whitespace characters are matched, then it matches the trailing whitespace.

https://regex101.com/r/AzOrJZ/4

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` keeps substituting the part of the string it has not yet matched until it reaches count or the end of the string, then it returns the remaining string.

Also your pattern could match zero characters.

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\s*(.*?)\s*')
>>> re.sub(pattern, r"\1", '   foo bar   ' , count=1)
'foobar   '
>>> re.sub(pattern, r"\1", 'foobar   ' , count=1)
 'foobar'
>>> re.sub(pattern, r"\1", '   foo bar   ' )
 'foobar'
```

If this suites your needs you can simplify your regex.

```
>>> re.sub(r"\s*", r"", '   foo bar   ' )
 'foobar'
```

If you only want to replace whitespace at the end of the string, use the following.

```
>>> re.sub(r"^\s*|\s*$", r"", '   foo bar   ' )
 'foo bar'
```